# Better to call child view method directly from parent, or by initiating a trigger?

Tags: marionette

I've got a complex Backbone/Marionette app and I'm often venting things out to parent elements . When I need to trigger things in children from parent elements though, it's a little unclear to me how I should be doing this. The easiest thing to do is just to call the method on the child from the parent, but, I wonder if I am "cheating" in this case (and perhaps causing memory leak issues or something?) and I'm curious about the "right" way.

[Here's a jsfiddle of an extremely simplified contrived version of my code.](http://jsfiddle.net/cmcculloh/aNmM6/) as well as [a gist of the same contrived example in a require based app](https://gist.github.com/cmcculloh/6270990).

```
<header>
    <h4>A subview/view trigger event loop playground</h4>
    <p>Open your console and then click the button</p>
</header>

<article id="main">
</article>

<script type="text/html" id="MySubView">
    <button type="button" id="button">Click Me</button>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="MyView">
    <div id="myRegion"></div>
</script>


<script>
var app = new Marionette.Application();

app.addRegions({
    "mainRegion": "#main" 
});

app.module("SampleModule", function(Mod, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

    var MySubView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: '#MySubView',
        events: {
            'click #button': 'sendClick'
        },

        triggers: {
            'afterClick': 'afterClick'
        },

        initialize: function initialize(){
            this.on('afterClick', this.afterClick);
        },

        sendClick: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('Good... Use your ventful capabilities boy...');
            //trigger some method in the parent...
            this.trigger('processClick');
        },

        afterClick: function(who) {
            console.log("I've been waiting for you... The circle is now complete. When I left you I was the but the sender, now I am the receiver...", who);
        }
    });

    var MyView = Marionette.Layout.extend({
        template: '#MyView',
        views: {},
        regions: {
            myRegion: '#myRegion'
        },

        onShow: function onShow(){
            this.views.mySubView = new MySubView({ model: this.model }).on('processClick', this.sendBackClick, this);
            this.myRegion.show(this.views.mySubView);
        },

        sendBackClick: function(){
            //do some stuff, then, let the child know you're done...
            console.log('heh heh heh heh.... Goood, goooood! Your triggers have made you powerful. Now, fulfil your parents destiny and take the event at my side!!!');
            //use trigger?
            this.views.mySubView.trigger('afterClick', 'from trigger');
            //call method directly?
            this.views.mySubView.afterClick('called directly');
        }
    });


    var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({

        initialize: function(options){
            this.region = options.region
        },

        show: function(){
            var mainView = new MyView({ model: new Backbone.Model({'prop':'value'}) });

            this.region.show(mainView);
        }
    });


    Mod.addInitializer(function(){
        Mod.controller = new Controller({
            region: app.mainRegion
        });
        Mod.controller.show();
    });
});

app.start();
</script>
```

As an aside: notice I'm using a 'view' property on the parent to keep track of it's children. If there's a better way to do this, or a reason as to why that's wrong I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things which may or may not answer your question:

First, in your contrived example it's pretty clear that you want the child to know that the 'click' has been processed by the parent, but in the real world I am guessing this may not actually be the relevant piece of information. Perhaps the child should be listening for something else altogether? For example, your layout and your child view happen to share a model. I'm going to take a leap and guess that the click event is actually meant to kick off some processing on that model. If that's the case maybe what the child really wants to know about is an event triggered on the model (either built-in or custom). In this way the child view could appropriately respond to the event even if it didn't come from the click in the first place (seems reasonable to me that there might someday be multiple paths). Granted, this is making a lot of assumptions. If it's not the model that is the center of this event it could still be something other than the child view - the app.vent? The parent layout itself? All depends on the exact use case.

Second, watch out for creating a views object when you define the layout. That will be a shared reference between the individual instances of the layout that you instantiate. It's possible that's what you want, but (assumptions again) I'm guess it's not.